# Find all $3×3$ matrices $A$ with eigenvalues 2 and 3

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all $3×3$ matrices $A$ with eigenvalues 2 and 3 (and no others) such that
the equations

$(A − 2Id)v = 0$ and $(A − 3Id)w = 0$
each have a 1-dimensional solution space.

I can get A has an eigenvector of eigenvalue 2 and an eigenvector of eigenvalue 3. How to find the remaining eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Comment: How did you get that $A$ is rank 2? (Just curious, since it can't be true - $0$ is not an eigenvalue).

Comment: There are an infinite number of them. Weren't you asked for these matrices up to similarity?

Comment: Are these matrices considered over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @user293121 Yes!

Comment: @mathguy Oh, I made a mistake. I assume that if a matrix does not have n linearly independent eigenvector then it's singular.

Comment: The trick has to do with Jordan normal form, did you study that yet?

Comment: @GitGud Yes, if we can use some variables to represent them, that's enough.

Comment: @Gatsby Then I suggest you reply to mathguy because JNF is the most natural way to go, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jordan canonical form must be either
$$ J_1 = \pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 3 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 3\cr}\ \text{or}\ 
J_2 = \pmatrix{2 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 3\cr}$$
Thus for some invertible matrix $B$, $A = B J_1 B^{-1}$ or $B J_2 B^{-1}$.

EDIT: This representation is not unique.  Thus $B_1 J_1 B_1^{-1} = B_2 J_1 B_2^{-1}$ iff $B_1^{-1} B_2$ commutes with $J_1$.